# Notice: Undefined index: id in ... on line

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$id = $_SESSION["id"];  
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
$surname = $_SESSION["surname"];

if (!empty($id)) {
    echo "<div id=\"user\">";
    echo "<h4>Utente: $name $surname | <a href=\"http:/...\">Logout</a></h4>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Problem:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in... on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: name in ... on line 5
>   Notice: Undefined index: surname in ... on line 6

So I try:

```
<?php
 session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!empty($_SESSION["id"])) {
    echo "<div id=\"user\">";
    echo "<h4>Utente: $_SESSION["name"] $_SESSION["surname"] | <a href=\"http:/...\">Logout</a></h4>";
    echo "</div>";
}?>
```

But:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ... on line 7

Why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about various errors, most [already asked on this website](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/871050), as well as syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all: this means that those variables are not set (i.e. do not exist). You need to check if they exist before trying to use them:

```
$id      = ($_SESSION["id"])      ?: null;  
$name    = ($_SESSION["name"])    ?: null;
$surname = ($_SESSION["surname"]) ?: null;
```

If you're running a version earlier than PHP 5.3 you would need to use the longer syntax:

```
$id      = (isset($_SESSION["id"]))      ? $_SESSION["id"]      : null;  
$name    = (isset($_SESSION["name"]))    ? $_SESSION["name"]    : null;
$surname = (isset($_SESSION["surname"])) ? $_SESSION["surname"] : null;
```

Comment: I forget, does that ternary operator check for `empty` or `isset`?

Comment: `Expression expr1 ?: expr3` returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise. I'm assuming it uses both as both are required for it to be true.

Comment: Give this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in ... on line 4

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: That's why. Use the second snippet I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) construct

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_SESSION["id"]))
{
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
}
if(isset($_SESSION["name"]))
{
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
}
if(isset($_SESSION["surname"]))
{
$surname = $_SESSION["surname"];
}
if (!empty($id)) {
    echo "<div id=\"user\">";
    echo "<h4>Utente: $name $surname | <a href=\"http:/...\">Logout</a></h4>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected**, You can use

```
echo "<h4>Utente: ".$_SESSION["name"] .$_SESSION["surname"] ."| <a href=\"http:/...\">Logout</a></h4>";
```

instead of

```
echo "<h4>Utente: $_SESSION["name"] $_SESSION["surname"] | <a href=\"http:/...\">Logout</a></h4>";
```

Updated Code:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        if (!empty($_SESSION["id"]) && isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
            echo "<div id=\"user\">";
              echo "<h4>Utente: ".$_SESSION["name"] .$_SESSION["surname"] ."| <a href=\"http:/...\">Logout</a></h4>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

    ?>
```